# Bootstrap navbar is expanding into the next container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, containers, navbar

My problem is that everything i put under the navbar ends up getting inside the navbar container. I'm sure it's something basic(like a forgotten div)  but i cant spot it. What's wrong with my code? Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Second Website</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">

        </script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- Navigation -->

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Name</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-database"></span>Products</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-book"></span>Contact</a>
                    </li>
                            <li class="slide"><a href="#" class="btn-slide1"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>Register</a></li>
                            <li class="slide"><a href="#" class="btn-slide2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                </ul>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>   


            <div class="container">

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

                        <!-- About us title and description-->

                            <h2>About us</h2>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent rhoncus ultricies nibh, vitae sodales purus. Aenean volutpat ullamcorper cursus. Duis tristique sit amet augue ac vestibulum.</p>



                        </div>

                    </div>


                </div>

            </div>


    </div> 
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

/* =========== NAVIGATION ============ */
.navbar { 
  min-height: 32px !important; 
}
 .navbar .navbar-brand{ 
  padding: 0 12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 38px;
  height: 38px; 
}
 .navbar .navbar-nav > li > a { 
  padding-top: 0px; 
  padding-bottom: 0px; 
  line-height: 38px; 
}
 .navbar .navbar-toggle { 
  margin-top: 3px; 
  margin-bottom: 0px; 
  padding: 8px 9px; 
}
 .navbar .navbar-collapse {
  border-color: #2f2f2f;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below css `class` and add into the `container`

```
.marginTop {
  margin-top:50px;
}
```

Here is working fiddle

**[update code](https://jsfiddle.net/v8o3j7wf/20/)**

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

/* =========== NAVIGATION ============ */
.navbar { 
  min-height: 32px !important; 
}
 .navbar .navbar-brand{ 
  padding: 0 12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 38px;
  height: 38px; 
}
 .navbar .navbar-nav > li > a { 
  padding-top: 0px; 
  padding-bottom: 0px; 
  line-height: 38px; 
}
 .navbar .navbar-toggle { 
  margin-top: 3px; 
  margin-bottom: 0px; 
  padding: 8px 9px; 
}
 .navbar .navbar-collapse {
  border-color: #2f2f2f;
}

.marginTop {
  margin-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Second Website</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">

        </script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- Navigation -->

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Name</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-database"></span>Products</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-book"></span>Contact</a>
                    </li>
                            <li class="slide"><a href="#" class="btn-slide1"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>Register</a></li>
                            <li class="slide"><a href="#" class="btn-slide2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                </ul>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>   


            <div class="container marginTop">

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

                        <!-- About us title and description-->

                            <h2>About us</h2>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent rhoncus ultricies nibh, vitae sodales purus. Aenean volutpat ullamcorper cursus. Duis tristique sit amet augue ac vestibulum.</p>



                        </div>

                    </div>


                </div>

            </div>


    </div> 
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: But i want it to be fixed at the top. How would that be affecting the next container? As for the last 3 divs, yes i removed them but still the same.

Comment: It worked , thank you. But why does the fixed-top command do this? Why does it overlapp with other containers?

Comment: An element with position: fixed; is positioned relative to the viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled. The top, right, bottom, and left properties are used to position the element.
A fixed element does not leave a gap in the page where it would normally have been located.